# Iterate through irregular tensor slices without for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to iterate through a tensor using slices of different (but fixed) length. The following sample code shows my actual proceeding:

```
slice_sizes = [10, 40, 80]
last_index = 0
top_scores = []
max_scores = tf.random.normal([130, 2])
scores = tf.random.normal([130,1])

for slice_size in slice_sizes:
    actual_slice = max_scores[last_index:last_index + slice_size]

    actual_slice_filtered_indices = tf.nn.top_k(actual_slice, k=10, sorted=True)[1] + last_index

    top_scores.append(
            tf.gather(scores, actual_slice_filtered_indices)
    )
```

Can anyone think on an optimal way of doing this **without the for loop**? It's creating a lot of unnecessary operations in the computation graph

Comment: What's your `max_scores` and `scores`? Please give a complete example.

Comment: I edited my code